# Docker: cannot access (jupyter data science) docker container with given IP address/token? Why is the port wrong?

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I mounted the Jupiter/Data Science docker container with this command: `docker run -p 7777:8888 --name DataS jupyter/datascience-notebook`

I get this reply:

> Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
>       to login with a token:
>       http://(c623e69fe641 or 127.0.0.1):8888/?token=0bf2a07b1dcd957f616e73941f5dc5dba4cd01d5341b21fd

Within Kinematik I get the same info.

But when I plug the address into the browser, the `127.0.0.1:8888 oder :7777`, I always get an error that the browser could not build any connection. (I tried several browsers)

Second point is that I thought I get the local port 7777 through this option `-p 7777:8888`. Why do I always keep getting 8888 as the local port?
I also tried `-p 8800:7777` but it gave me the same results :-(

The reason I want to change this is the fact that my local apache web server is running on this port.

What am I doing wrong? (regarding the access as well as the port mapping)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in networking mode. Fast solution - use `--network=host`. In this scenario you don't need port forwarding, nor IP addresses or host names - docker container just uses host networking:

```
docker run --network=host --name DataS jupyter/datascience-notebook
```

Then connect using `localhost`:

```
http://localhost:8888
```

The drawback of `host` network mode is the lack of container isolation, which in your case is probably not needed.

Deeply what is happening in your case:

- Your service starts in container, opens port `8888`. But it **doesnt** know it is inside container, that's why it asks you to connect using `http://localhost:8888`. in fact it would work, but only **from inside** the container.
- on your HOST pc you map container's port `8888` to `7777`, but you cannot use `localhost` as soon as you should put your container's IP address or host name.

If you dont wanna use `host` network because of security issues or port conflicts, just connect using container's IP address.
Launch container:

```
docker run -p 7777:8888 --name DataS jupyter/datascience-notebook
```

Get container's ip:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' DataS
```

Connect with `http://[container ip]:7777`

Comment: Thanks. OK. Unfortunately as soon as my web server runs I get the standard php site. So this is ok as long as the web server is off. Do have a "slow solution" too?

Comment: Assuming the environment isn't Docker Toolbox or Docker Machine, `http://localhost:7777` _should_ work (using the mapped port, calling from a browser on the same host).  `docker inspect` to find the container-private IP address is distinctly not a best practice.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. The only docker container that really works for me this: tylerfowler/superset.
But it runs some config script before starting the server.

Comment: Are you sure, `jupyter` links to proper interface, not `localhost`? I mean when you start service, you normally specify also interface and port, but interface should be `0.0.0.0` rather then `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` to enable connections from aside

Comment: Found this: https://medium.com/@balint_sera/access-macos-host-from-a-docker-container-e0c2d0273d7f